Proof that if idempotent commutes with all nilpotent that it belong to center of ring $Z(R)$
Let $R$ - a associative ring with 1. Let $e \in R$ - an idempotent ($e^2 = e$). I want to proof fact, that if $e$ commutes with all nilpotents of $R$ then $e \in Z(R)$.
My ideas. Let $r$ - an arbitraty element in $R$ and $a$ - nilpotent element in $R$ ($a^n = 0$ for some $n$). I want to proof that $er = re$. To show it i want to show that $re - er = 0$. I tried to expand expression $a (re - er) = are - aer = are - ear$, but how to show that it is equal to zero?

Let $e\in R$ be such an idempotent and let $r\in R$, we have
$$ (er-ere)^2=erer-erere-ere^2r+ere^2re=0 $$
so $er-ere$ is nilpotent. Thus
$$ e(er-ere)=(er-ere)e $$
which implies $er=ere$. The same can be said of $re-ere$, this implies that $re=ere=er$ and we're done.

Thanks for helping! I tried to proof by expanding $(er - are)^n$, but it looks very simple.
